# Condition for identity of signs in regular expression pattern

Tags: c#, regex

Is there any way to create pattern using regular expression that will work like this: a letter, sign & or |, a letter (where the first and the second letters are the same). I know that pattern

```
[a-z](\\s*)[&|](\\s*)[a-z]
```

don't work in this way. How to define that this letters should be the same? Is it possible to create something like alias in regular expression pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using back references like this:

```
([a-zA-Z])\s*[&|]\s*\1
```

This first matches a letter `([a-zA-Z])` and puts that letter inside capturing group 1, then it tries to match `&` or `|` using `[&|]`, then it tries to match the same character that was matched in group 1 using `\1`.